# Apex Paramater always null

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, callback

I have an Apex method `createRecurringEngagements` that accepts a Boolean parameter `jewishEducator` (the last param). I print the parameter in the Apex class but it is always null. I tried accepting jewishEducator as a String instead of a Boolean but that didn't work. I also console.log the jewishEducator value in my aura helper method before calling the apex method, and it correctly prints the value. **Why is the parameter always null in the Apex class?**

**Apex class:**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Engagement__c> createRecurringEngagements( String engagementTitle , String engagementType , String engagementSubType , String engagementStartDate
            ,String engagementEndDate, String recurrencePattern , String numberOfRecurrences , String recurringFrequency , Id campus, String participants,
            String selectedWeekDay, String selectedWeekNumber, String selectedDayOfMonth, String[] engagerIds, String jewishEducatorString) {

        System.debug('jewishEducator: ' + jewishEducatorString); //always prints null
```

**Aura helper method:**

```
createRecurringEngagements: function(cmp, event){
        let createEngagementsAction = cmp.get('c.createRecurringEngagements');
let createRecur = cmp.find('createRecurringEngagement');
let jewishEducator = createRecur.get('v.newEngagement.Jewish_Educator__c');
        if(jewishEducator === undefined) {
            jewishEducator = false;
        }
jewishEducator = JSON.stringify(jewishEducator);
console.log('final jewishEducator: ' + jewishEducator); //always prints correctly

createEngagementsAction.setParams({
        "engagementTitle": title,
        "engagementStartDate": startDate,
        "engagementEndDate": endDate,
        "engagementType": engType,
        "engagementSubType": subType,
        "recurrencePattern": recPattern,
        "recurringFrequency": recEveryValue,
        "numberOfRecurrences": numberRecur,
        "campusId": campusId,
        "participants": JSON.stringify(contactList),
        "selectedWeekDay": selectedDayOfWeek,
        "selectedWeekNumber": selectedWeekNumber,
        "selectedDayOfMonth": selectedDayOfMonth,
        "engagerIds": engagerIds,
        "jewishEducatorString:": jewishEducator
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class you are declaring the variable name as `jewishEducatorString` however, when you are setting parameters in your client side controller you are  attempting to pass it as `jewishEducator`.

so, by changing

```
"jewishEducator:": jewishEducator
```

to

```
"jewishEducatorString:": jewishEducator
```

should do the trick.

One last thing, ensure that your variables are of the same type when passing from one controller to another.